# Why is SurveyQuestion.QuestionType displaying as a numerical value in a report?

Tags: configuration, custom-report-type

This field (SurveyQuestion.QuestionType) is described as a picklist in the [object reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_surveyquestion.htm?q=survey).

When I query it via SOQL, it indeed behaves like a picklist:   select QuestionType from SurveyQuestion shows outputs like FreeText, Rating, etc.  -- Great!

When I include this field in a custom report type, however, it looks like a number.   A simple report that illustrates this uses SurveyQuestion as primary object.    This field displays as a number in the report, e.g. 3, 5, 17 -- not even consecutive numbers.   This seems like a bug.

If there is no fix for this, I would settle for a key that interprets the numbers.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken this to concern product development team internally and have heard back that the issue is because QuestionType field is of type Enum in salesforce.  Use below values for corresponding picklist values.

```
MULTI_CHOICE("0", "MultiChoice"),
RADIO_BUTTON("1", "RadioButton"),
FREE_TEXT("2", "FreeText"),
DATE("3", "Date"),
RATING("4", "Rating"),
CSAT("5", "CSAT"),
SLIDER("6", "Slider"),
PICKLIST("7", "Picklist"),
NPS("8", "NPS"),
STACK_RANK("9", "StackRank"),
CURRENCY("10", "Currency"),
NUMBER("11", "Number"),
DATE_TIME("12", "DateTime"),
TOGGLE("13", "Toggle"),
MULTI_SELECT_PICKLIST("14", "MultiSelectPicklist"),
IMAGE("15", "Image"),
BOOLEAN("16", "Boolean"),
SHORT_TEXT("17", "ShortText"),
ATTACHMENT("18", "Attachment"),
MATRIX("19", "Matrix"),
```

We are coordinating with documentation team to have this added to public facing document. I will update this thread as I have more inputs on it.

Comment: Thanks, Sai!   the explanation makes sense and meshes with the data I am seeing..